# CGI/FastCGI Request variable error?

Tags: php, apache, cgi, fastcgi

Hi I recently updated mysites working file to a CGI/FastCGI server. 
It have some request variable section to process.

`oldsite.com/myfile.php?link=http://google.com` [Working fine in apache]

`oldsite.com/myfile.php?link=http://google` [Working fine in apache]

`oldsite.com/myfile.php?link=http://google.com` [Not Working in CGI/FastCGI ]

`oldsite.com/myfile.php?link=http://google` [Working in CGI/FastCGI ]

any one know what was wrong in  CGI/FastCGI???

Answer (score 0):

I would allege that you also enabled `mod_security`. Look into the `error.log`. It would tell you the exact error condition. (Add the error message to your question!)

The `?link=` parameter is not a significant name in the CGI environment. It might however be blacklisted by the mod_security CoreRules. (Run into the very same URL blocking issue before.)

Comment: let me check that, on the error log i didn;t find that kinda o error.

Comment: Else explain *what* your "not working" description amounts to.

Comment: I will enable thatin 20minute.. wll let u know. thank for the support.

Comment: they are saying its enabled? Where can I check this enabled or not? Using phpinfo(); ??

Comment: It's an Apache module. Check out `/etc/apache2/*.*` - but sounds like you have an hosting provider; so ask them again.

Comment: Yes i asked them, they are saying that, its already enabled>> Is there any other  method to check using php?

Comment: You cannot check it with php.